# Kotlin, reduce duplicated code

Tags: kotlin

Every my API service interface class have create static method,

```
interface AuthApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/auth/login")
    fun postLogin(@Field("username") username: String, @Field("password") password: String):
            io.reactivex.Observable<LoginApiResponse>

    companion object Factory {
        fun create(): AuthApiService {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .baseUrl("http:192.168.24.188:8080")
                    .build()
            return retrofit.create(AuthApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}


interface BBBApiService {
    companion object Factory {
        fun create(): BBBApiService {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .baseUrl("http:192.168.24.188:8080")
                    .build()
            return retrofit.create(BBBApiService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

But, I want to define the create() method only once.

So I made the ApiFactory class,

```
interface ApiFactory {
    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T>createRetrofit(): T {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.24.188:8080")
                    .build()

            return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
        }


    }
}

interface AuthApiService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("api/auth/login")
    fun postLogin(@Field("username") username: String, @Field("password") password: String):
            io.reactivex.Observable<LoginApiResponse>

    companion object Factory {
        fun create(): AuthApiService {
            return ApiFactory.createRetrofit()
        }
    }
```

But, still, I need to define the create() method in AuthApiService.

Is there any a way implement the ApiFactory class to SubApi classes so that I don't have to define the create method in each child classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is just to call the function of your `ApiFactory` directly:

```
val authApiService = ApiFactory.createRetrofit<AuthApiService>()
```

---

But if you want to be able to call `AuthApiService.create()`, then you can define a marker interface, say, `ApiFactoryClient<T>`, and mark an empty `companion object` with it.

```
interface ApiFactoryClient<T>

interface AuthApiService {
    /* ... */

    companion object : ApiFactoryClient<AuthApiService>
}
```

And then make an extension function that works with `ApiFactoryClient<T>`:

```
inline fun <reified T> ApiFactoryClient<T>.create(): T = ApiFactory.createRetrofit<T>()
```

And the usage would be:

```
val authApiService = AuthApiService.create()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your `ApiFactory` like this:

```
interface ApiFactory {
    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T>createRetrofit(klass: KClass<T>): T {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.24.188:8080")
                    .build()

            return retrofit.create(klass.java)
        }


    }
}
```

And then use it to create different service instances:

```
val authApiService = ApiFactory.createRetrofit(AuthApiService::class)
```

Comment: I think there's no need to change the signature. Why not simply call the function as `val authApiService = ApiFactory.createRetrofit<AuthApiService>()`?

Comment: @hotkey you're right, this should work fine, I'm just new to Kotlin